# Django Template: How to use parent variable in nested for loop

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

```
{% for round in rounds %}
  <div id="round_{{forloop.counter}}">
    {% for match in r{{forloop.counter}}_matches %}
        <p>I am match {{ match }}!</p>
        <p>I am one of the matches in round {{round}}!</p>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

`rounds` and `r1_matches, r2_matches` etc. are lists of objects defined in the view that leads to this template.

Obviously, this snippet is showing logically what I want to happen, but it doesn't work for obvious reasons.  In lieu of being able to use `{{forloop.counter}}` inside the second `for` loop, how can I go about only loading up matches that are a part of the current round?

As a side note, I also have a variable being passed to this template which isn't shown here, called `matches`, and each `match` object has a field called `round` which tells you which round that match belongs in.  I figured I would do more of the logic in the view, though, and so I have `r1_matches, r2_matches` etc. pre-snipped out into their own lists.  Point being, if it makes more sense to do something like `{% for match|"round={{forloop.counter}}" in matches %}` I would gladly do it, but then I STILL need access to the parent loop's counter same as the other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

really you should do

```
context = {"rounds":[["match1","match2","match3"],["match2","match1"]]

{% for round in rounds %}
   <div id="round_{{forloop.counter0}}">
      {% for match in round %}
          I am match {{forloop.counter1}}
          in round {{forloop.counter0 }}
      {% endfor %}
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I think thats right at least ...

iirc `counter0` is the outermost forloop ,`counter1` is the next inner (I think you can go as far as 9)

`counter` refers to the current one

Comment: Ah! I've been looking at it too long.  Just one more packaging step in the view and all is well.  Thanks friend!